# Dynamic dates in Moment JS

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am trying to display a graph with orders made each day. My idea is to show the orders from current date until previous week. So seven days starting from today. Is there something in Moment js that can give me that? Or should I use the current date and subtract one day from it using a loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [manipulating](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/):

```
moment().subtract(7, 'days')
```